# Get data from a site's source code in php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to get some data from a site's source code and edit that source then add it to a database. I know about php's `file_get_contents` function but I don't know how to get my data with this method.

Original source:

```
<div id="wwww" class="ssss">
<div id="1" class="2"><p>my data : </p><div id="a" class="b">i want this data</div>
<div class="action">delete</div></div>
</div>
```

Getting div source with id `1` and deleting div source with class `action` and finally print data like so:

```
<div id="1" class="2"><p>my data :</p><div id="a" class="b">i want this data</div></div>
```

Please introduce me to php functions for this method that can be used.

Comment: See libxml or other libraries for working with xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). It's very easy to use:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$myDiv = $html->find('div[id=1]');
```

Comment: very very thanks . that very usefull but i have a small problem with removing some tag . how i can remove from : <div id="1" class="2"><p>my data :</p><div id="a" class="b">i want this data</div></div>  and only printing : <div id="1" class="2"><p>my data :</p></div>